# Sorting Dates in ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combo box with the following dates: 1/27/2014, 1/5/2014,12/20/2013

How can i sort them based on year then month, it appears that the:

```
combobox.sorted = true
```

works based on first character

how can i sort to show the december date first

Comment: can you not do the sorting on the values before you populate the combo box?

Comment: @ric i add them to combobox as i "create" them.  do you suggest adding them to an array or list then sort?  if so please demonstate how to sort a list by dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the default sort of a list of dates before adding the list as a datasource:

```
    Dim Dates As List(Of Date) =
        {
            Date.Parse("1/27/2014"),
            Date.Parse("1/5/2014"),
            Date.Parse("12/20/2013")
        }.ToList
    Dates.Sort()
    ComboBox1.DataSource = Dates
```

To sort descending you can use Reverse after the collection is sorted.  It would be more proper to sort in descending order rather that iterating through the collection twice.  A custom comparison would work here:

```
Dates.Sort(New Comparison(Of Date)(Function(x As Date, y As Date) y.CompareTo(x)))
```

Comment: (more or less like mine answer) But, just for your information, I tested this approach (Sort/Reverse) before considering LINQ and does not seem to deliver good results. More specifically, I tested with these specific dates and the results weren't right (with Reverse, at least).

Comment: There's an aspect of reverse that gets many people.  It needs a proper sort first then it reverses the sort correctly.  Sort uses the default comparer of the objects being sorted.  As long as the class implements a comparer it will work according to how that comparer is designed.

Comment: You seem to be right: if I apply Sort and then Reverse, it seems to work fine. Perhaps you should clarify this issue in your answer. PS: I didn't look too much into the issue; I use sort/reverse only for strings, so when I saw a problem, just moved to LINQ; seemed a bit weird to me but... (in my afternoon I am not feeling like investigating these things :))

Comment: Not really weird since Reverse isn't a sorting algorithm it's a reversing algorithm.  So whatever order the collection is in, Reverse just reverses it.  It doesn't apply any sorting.  Btw, combobox items are objects, they are only displayed as strings.

Comment: This is clear now and I would have it clear if I would go to the Reverse MSDN article instead to the Sort one. But A PRIORI, intuitively, it does seem to be the inverse of Sort and, as you can see, in my answer; LINQ has the same ordering/inverse-ordering and both work independently, as is expected from an ordering/inverse ordering. From this answer it is pretty clear that I don't use Reverse too much; but seemed a more evident implementation and that's why I planned to suggest it in its evident configuration (same than Sort but the contrary); when my test told me that this wasn't the case...

Comment: ... I stopped considering it as the evident functionality which it seemed to be and thus didn't include it in my answer (but an approach that I know that works perfectly; and that understands exactly as I do the concept of sorting/inverse-sorting). The fact of not having used it rightly or having a 20-year old bug in .NET is irrelevant; the relevant fact is that it does not deliver the functionality which intuitively (at least, for me) is expected to deliver and thus you should mention this issue. This is my opinion; you are free to have a different one.

Comment: Since the sort has a capability to implement sorting by different criteria a descending sorter is easily implemented.  It might not be as obvious as the orderby methods but it is there.

Comment: Sure, I don't doubt that. Just said that it is not too evident. After a hard day and at around this time (and later) I become a pretty accurate detector of what is not so evident. I wouldn't have had this conversation 8 hours ago ;)